# Passing specific of multiple sql query output to form dynamically

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

The query works fine. I get a table with the associated data in rows. As you see I'd like a button with each row that calls a function that affects that specific row with which it is echoed. I have it working with a normal form, that is, If I put the value of Part_Number in manually the function will run successfully, but the issue is to have it more dynamic. I provided the applicable code.

In short: When I push the button that is echoed with the Part_Number it should update (add one) to the Quantity of that Part_Number.

The SQL doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't work. Everything except passing the variables dynamically works.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, Part_Number, Description, Location, Quantity, Certificate 
FROM Inventory WHERE Part_Number LIKE'%$q%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  echo "
  <form method='POST' action='plusone.php'><tbody>
  <tr>
  <th><h2>".$row["Part_Number"]."</h2></th>
  <td><h2>".$row["Description"]."</h2> </td>
    <td><h2>".$row["Location"]."</h2> </td>
    <td>
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Plus 1'>

    <input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='Part_Number_Entry' 
 id='$Part_Number_Entry' value=''>

 </tr>

 </tbody>
  </form>";


if (isset($Part_Number1)) {



// the single quotes around the last variable are very important. If left out 
the update wont work
$sql = "UPDATE TestTable SET Quantity= Quantity + 1 WHERE Part_Number= 
'$Part_Number1'";

}elseif (!isset($PartNumber)) {
echo "PartNumber is not set"; 
    # code...
}
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "Added One to current Record successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
  echo $Quantity;
 echo "   ";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Where and how is `$Part_Number1` assigned as?

Comment: you're only checking if the query failed, not via php.

Comment: you posted this already https://stackoverflow.com/q/52862902/ and that was closed. Only there could I see where you assigned `$Part_Number1=$_REQUEST['Part_Number_Entry'];`.

Comment: your button link has the Certificate, not the Part_Number

Comment: `href`'s are not considered as (form) inputs. Plus, there are missing `<table></table>` tags. If you have them elsewhere, then `<form>` cannot be made a child of `<table>`.

Comment: That's my question. How do I assign $Part_Number1 dynamically. from the top query I get a table with multiple rows, all with their respective Part_Number. I tried setting $Part_Number1  equal to the value of the form which I tried to make equal to the output of the first query. It didn't work. That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: That was a different issue. Not the same question at all

Comment: I'm referring to the Plus 1 button. @IdontDownVote

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner, Thanks you for informing me that <form> cannot be made a child of <table>. Great information but it doesn't solve my issue. Why do people downvote? Is the question poorly worded or what?

Comment: I did not down vote, but when some one posts a questions with so many 'basic' errors it tends to attract negative attention. SO is not a great resoruce for a beginner.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

there are quite a few issues but this is the least code i could come up wit that will hopefully get you at least going in the right direction:

```
<input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='Part_Number_Entry' id='$Part_Number_Entry' value=''>
```

should be

```
<input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='Part_Number_Entry'  value='$row["Part_Number_Entry"]' >
```

its the 'name' that becomes the array key and the value is from your db row

```
if (isset($Part_Number1)) {
```

should be

```
if (isset($_POST['Part_Number_Entry')) {
```

your posting the form, and the value you want is in that array.

To get `$Part_Number1` for the query

```
$Part_Number1=(int)$_POST['Part_Number_Entry');
```

cast as int by you need to much safer db queries in the future.

This is not a great answer and i hope some posts something better.